# Display checkbox name when they are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I m trying to implant one function to display name (not value) of checkbox when they are selected. I m on Ruby on Rail app.

So my jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[name="animaux"]').click(function () {
                getSelectedCheckBoxes('animaux');
            });
            $('input[name="handicap"]').click(function () {
                getSelectedCheckBoxes('handicap');
            });
            $('input[name="television"]').click(function () {
                getSelectedCheckBoxes('television');
            });
            $('input[name="barbecue"]').click(function () {
                getSelectedCheckBoxes('barbecue');
            });
            var getSelectedCheckBoxes = function (groupName) {
                var result = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:checked');
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    var resultString = "";
                    result.each(function () {
                        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                        resultString += groupName + " - "
                            + $('label[for="option-' + selectedValue + '"]').text() + "<br/>";
                    });
                    $('#divfilter').html(resultString);
                }
                else {
                    $('#divfilter').html("");
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Filters are displayed with

```
<div id="divfilter"></div>
```

And checkbox look like this

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="barbecue" id="barbecue" value="oui" class="barbecue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="handicap" id="handicap" value="oui" class="handicap" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animaux" id="animaux" value="oui" class="animaux" />
```

**Question 1 :**
When i select one checkbox thats works. But if i select 2 checkbox the first label name is replace by the new one. I want those 2 labels. How i can do that ?

**Question 2:**
Any idea to simplified and DRY this ?

```
$('input[name="animaux"]').click(function () {
                    getSelectedCheckBoxes('animaux');
                });
                $('input[name="handicap"]').click(function () {
                    getSelectedCheckBoxes('handicap');
                });
                $('input[name="television"]').click(function () {
                    getSelectedCheckBoxes('television');
                });
                $('input[name="barbecue"]').click(function () {
                    getSelectedCheckBoxes('barbecue');
                });
```

**Question 3 :**
Any idea to implant a cross for "unselect" between the name ?

Thanks for your help !

By the way sorry for my bad english I m french...

Comment: May we have some `label` HTML code please

Comment: I edited my post with checkbox input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// find and retrieve all <input> elements of
// 'type=checkbox':
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

// use the on() method to bind the anonymous function
// as the event-handler of the 'change' event:
checkboxes.on('change', function(){

  // update the '#divfilter' element's text:
  $('#divfilter').text(function(){

    // we return the following as the new text:

    // first we filter the checkboxes collection to
    // retain only those that match the ':checked'
    // pseudo-class, and then create a map:
    return checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){

      // the contents of the map are comprised of
      // the 'name' property of each checked check-box:
      return this.name;

    // we convert the map() into an Array, using get():
    }).get()

    // and join the Array elements together with the
    // supplied String, and finished with a period:
    .join(', ') + '.';
  });
});
```

```js
// find and retrieve all <input> elements of
// 'type=checkbox':
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

// use the on() method to bind the anonymous function
// as the event-handler of the 'change' event:
checkboxes.on('change', function() {

  // update the '#divfilter' element's text:
  $('#divfilter').text(function() {

    // we return the following as the new text:

    // first we filter the checkboxes collection to
    // retain only those that match the ':checked'
    // pseudo-class, and then create a map:
    return checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {

      // the contents of the map are comprised of
      // the 'name' property of each checked check-box:
      return this.name;

      // we convert the map() into an Array, using get():
    }).get()

    // and join the Array elements together with the
    // supplied String, and finished with a period:
    .join(', ') + '.';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="barbecue" id="barbecue" value="oui" class="barbecue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="handicap" id="handicap" value="oui" class="handicap" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animaux" id="animaux" value="oui" class="animaux" />

<div id="divfilter"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/auqt03wk/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks for yout reply. I tested your code but nothing display when i checked one checkbox or more... :(

Comment: The Snippet I just added, below the code visible in the question, demonstrates that this does work with the code you've provided (though I've had to add the `<div id="divfilter"></div>` element myself); are you getting different behaviour?

Comment: thats really great !! Thanks for your help :) It's work like a charm. By the way do you have any idea for my question number 3 ?

Comment: The OP might consider also a class on the check boxes to "group" them and not effect other checkboxes that might be on the page

Comment: One question per question, @nicolaswecandoit; while I have a couple of ideas that's extending the question into something of a project. If you can't find a satisfactory answer elsewhere on the site consider asking a new question to address that problem (though linking to this question to show context for the problem).

Comment: @DavidThomas ok understood. Thanks for your help and reference :)

Comment: @DavidThomas I have another question with your code. How i can do if I want to add filter in class for exemple i select "handicap" and "barbecue" i want this result <div id="divfilter"><div class="aclass">handicap</div><div class="aclass">barbecue</div></div>

Comment: @DavidThomas nice example! OP: here is a worked up version with some alternative markup extrapolated from this answer https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/wqwy93mz/

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for this update. I m tried your code, unfornutualy that doesnt work for me. Problem is ".checkgroup". Nothing display. I dont know why because that's work on fiddle. If i remove the first one .checkgroup on line 2 checkbox label are displayed but remove doesnt work...